# Сортировка по русскому алфавиту С++

Tags: c++, строки, сортировка

В задании по С++ сказанно отсортирвать массив названий товаров продуктового магазина по алфавиту на русском. С английской сортировкой в Java мне все проще - я просто подключала библиотеку и вызывала пару методов, а тут прямо ступор.

Comment: 1) использовать специальные библиотеки типа [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/); 2) если нужен только русский алфавит, то достаточно вручную задать массив или карту, задающую порядок на множестве русских букв; после этого легко написать компаратор, упорядочивающий русские буквы

Comment: #include <algorithm> и использовать std::sort, если вам надо потом вывести на консоль, то добавить setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian")

Comment: Если отбросить букву `ёЁ`, то во всех популярных кодировках кириллица упорядочена при беззнаковом сравнении

Answer (score 0):

Пример для строк:

```
auto a = std::vector<std::string>{
  "Зебра",
  "ягоды",
  "Арбуз",
  "Яблоко",
};

std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), std::locale("ru_RU.UTF-8"));
```

Для объектов расширяется элементарно.

Comment: 1) локаль `ru_RU.UTF-8` не является стандартной; 2) попробуйте добавить слово "Ёж", например

Comment: 1) Что вы имеете в виду? Что на ОС может не быть? 2) У меня "Ёж" и "ёлка" сортируются верно.

Comment: 1) да, единственная не implementation-defined локаль - "C"; 2) это зависит от представления букв. В UTF-8 "ё" представлена байтами, большими чем остальной алфавит

Comment: У меня, например, нет `std::collate` для "ru_RU.UTF-8", поэтому для "C" локали, в соответствии с [байтовым представлением](https://unicode-table.com/en/#cyrillic) (исходник в `UTF-8`) "Ёж" всегда вначале, а "ёж" всегда в конце. Для текущей пользовательской локали (пустая строка - "") "Ёж" после "ёж", но перед "ёлка" и т.п.

Comment: 1) ОП ничего не указала про ОС, так что думаю можно предположить, что у неё ОС, которая поддерживает русскую локаль. Иначе да, понадобится поставлять свою имплементацию. 2) Русская локаль умеет это понимать, так же как турецкая понимает, что заглавная форма "i" для неё должна быть "İ", а не "I".